# How to extract Mongoid documents based on a field value in the first or last embedded document?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I wish to find `Order` documents based on a field in the last embedded `Notification`document.

In the example below I wish to find all `pending` `orders` that has one or more embedded `notifications`, and where the last `notification` has a `datetime` that is between 5 and 10 days old.

My suggestion here dosen't seem to do the trick...:

```
Order.where(status: 'pending').gte('notifications.last.datetime' => 5.days.ago).lte('notifications.last.datetime' => 10.days.ago)
```

Here are the two models:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :datetime, type: DateTime
  field :status, type: String, default: 'pending'
  embeds_many :notifications,  :inverse_of => :order
end

class Notification
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :datetime, type: DateTime
  embedded_in :order, :inverse_of => :notifications
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue of the question seems to be how to refer to the LAST element of an array in the query.

Unfortunately, it is impossible as of MongoDB 2.4.
The simplest way to implement this feature is to use negative value to point to an element in an array like `'notifications.-1.datetime'`, but it doesn't work. (Refer to [[#SERVER-5565] Handle negative array offsets consistently - MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5565).)

To make matters worse, it also seems impossible to solve this using Aggregation Framework.  There is no way to
add an array index to each element when `$unwind`ing ([[#SERVER-4588] aggregation: add option to $unwind to emit array index - MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588)) or
select the index of an array dynamically when `$project`ing. ([[#SERVER-4589] aggregation: need an array indexing operator - MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589))

Therefore, the only option you have seem to change the schema to match what you want.  The simplest way is to add to `Order` one more field which contains `datetime` of the last `Notification`.

**Update:**

You can first get all candidates from the server, and then narrow down them on the client side to get the final result set.  This involves no schema change.  If the scale of database is relatively small or some degradation of performance is acceptable, this might be the best solution.

```
query = Order.where(status: 'pending').elem_match(
  notifications: { datetime: { '$gte' => 10.days.ago, '$lte' => 5.days.ago } })
query.select do |order|
  # datetime = order.notifications[0].datetime
  datetime = order.notifications[order.notifications.size - 1].datetime
  10.days.ago <= datetime && datetime <= 5.days.ago
end.each do |order|
  p order # result
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough research @Akihiro Harai. Unfortunately, in this case, it is not always the last `notification` that is needed, but sometime the first instead, so putting in an extra field in `Order` would not a stabile solution for me. Do you have an idea for to solve the sorting with a mongoid query, followed by some Ruby logic?

Comment: You can refer to the first element with `notifications.0.datetime`.  But if you really don't want to change the schema, there is another way.  First get candidates from the server, and then narrow them down to the result on the client side.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want :-) It would seem reasonable to just change the schema, but in many other aspects it makes much sense to let my relation stay embedded. So if you are able to put together a piece of code that gets candidates from the server, and then narrow down on the client side (or in this case it would be in a controller of my Rails app) I would be immensely greatfull.

Comment: Updated the answer. How about this one?

Answer (score 0):

I know it comes a little late, but hey, better later than never. :P

You can use JavaScript in where:

```
Order.where("this.notifications[this.notifications.length - 1].datetime > new Date('#{5.days.ago}')")
```

Just found out that and was a huge relief having not to change my models. Hope that helps!